# Looking for a script similar to jquery.inview that allows div to be loaded as user scrolls

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've been searching tirelessly to find a script that as a user scrolls down a page, content is loaded.

I have a page with multiple images that span down a page and would like to use this script to speed up the initial page load. The content on the page is static, so I would prefer the content to be appended to the page as it is scrolled.

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for this. With jQuery you can do

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      //Add something at the end of the page
   }
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/6hPHn/2/

Comment: $('.div').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
                        if (visible) {
                            $(this).css('display', 'block');
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).stop().css('display', 'none');
                        }

                    });

something like this is what i am after ... but still isn't working correctly

Comment: Your questions was you wanted something similar to inview. inview is not a jQuery function. If you are using a plugin, refer to it's documentation. In my example i showed you how it's done without using a plugin,

Answer (score 2):

Depending what exactly you are trying to load and when, [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) might be part of a potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

This library adds an inview event to bind to so it's really easy to read and maintain.  https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview  I've also used Waypoints but I feel this is a easier to get started with.

`$("#divId").on("inview" fn);`

```
$("#loadMeLater").on("inview",function(){
  // Remove event handler after the element has been viewed
  $(this).off("inview");
  // Change something on screen after a short timer
  setTimeout(inViewHandler,'200');
});
```